# Questions about Satan

Tags: islamic-philosophy, shaitan

These questions were asked from a none-believer person, I really couldn't answer him because of my lack of knowledge:

1. If *satan* helps humans to make a mistake,  who made *Satan* made
   his mistake?
2. *Satan* made Adam and his wife to not obey God's word, but Adam and Hawa were in Janna at that time, what did *Satan* do in Janna? He supposed to be outside of Janna because of Not obeying.
3. *Satan* have generation(I mean he can have son...), but his son's have no ability to convert to Islam, But this is  Not their fault if they born like a *Satan*.

Hopefully, you're understand my question.
Again, these question didn't asked by me.
I am just looking for answers. 
Thanks again and Jazakum allah jami'an.

Comment: This question is too broad for one question. Please break it down into separate question across different posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must consult Ulama (Islamic scholars) for a reliable answer. Anyway following is my understanding.

1. Iblis/Satan only whispers or incites human to make mistakes. Beside Satan, nafs (lower self, ego) plays a major role in disobeying God.
2. Iblis mislead Adam and Eve to eat forbidden fruit, telling them, by eating it, they will become like angels and will be more closer to God. It is more complex than simply making a mistake.
3. Quran does not talk in details about Satan but only enough to protect ourselves from his mischief. Nevertheless, I read somewhere that Iblis is to Jins what Adam is to men. That is an archetype. It is known that a group of jins came to Prophet (pbuh) and embraced Islam.

Comment: was Satan banned from the heavens when he refused god order to prostrate to Adam or after whispering them to eat from the forbidden fruit?

Comment: I think satan does not need physical manifestation to whisper. There is a saying (hadeeth) that satan is with us as long as we have circulation of blood in our body. In other word, he is a constant companion, who conspire with nafs (lower-nafs), to bring dishonor (take away the position God gave to human). Many people get freaked out about him but for muslims satan is just a being, who has no control on human other than inciting nafs toward shameful actions.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1 already answered by ZAM perfectly.

Point 2: It was not necessary for Satan to be present to whisper to Adam. He could use

the help of other creatures having access to them. There are narrations speaking of a

snake and the like, who acted in the middle. Whether these narrations are authentic or

not, the space for a third person in between cannot be taken away. Whatever, the case,

what matters really is that he made them to eat from the tree, and not by which means he

used. Also there is a misconception among people that it was a single or a few occasions

in total, that Satan used to make his plot successful. But, in fact, it was a long

gradual process in itself, as implied by the word 'Fadalla' in Quran-7:22.

Point 3: Why do you think that his progeny has no ability to accept Islam? Here you are

going against the basic principle that Iblis is among the Jinn and they have a free-will.

With the exception of the Iblis himself, who has gone astray for the eternal, other

Shayateen of lower grade should be having the free will to accept or reject Islam.Also

consider this hadith:
It was narrated that ‘Abd-Allah ibn Mas’ood said: The Messenger of Allah (peace and

blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “There is no one among you but a companion from

among the jinn has been assigned to him.” They said, “Even you, O Messenger of Allah?’ He

said, “Even me, but Allah helped me with him and he became Muslim (or: and I am safe from

him), so he only enjoins me to do that which is good.” 
Regarding the above hadith, there is a difference of opinion on whether Messenger(pbuh)

converted him to Islam or He only disciplined him. Even if the jinn did not convert, he

was made to do something which is against his very nature, which gives a hint about his

changing nature. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: was Satan banned from the heavens when he refused god order to prostrate to Adam or after whispering them to eat from the forbidden fruit?  because if he was banned by the time he refused to bound then he couldn't have been in heavens with Adam to whisper to him?

Answer (score 0):

1/ When Allah (God) created Adam he ordered all his other creations (angels,djinns and satan which were created from fire) to kneel to him because he was created from clay, at that moment , satan (iblis) was the only one who refused to do so pretending that fire-made creatures cannot kneel to clay-made ones because fire is superior to clay,and Violated God's orders. So, allah punished him and and moved him to hell, that's when satan said that these creatures were very weak and that he would make them disobei allah orders just by inciting them to do so.and he requested from Allah permission to that saying "i will bring them all to hell with me ", then Allah replied (with the meaning) they will not follow you !

This was about the story of the mistake satan made, now, about "who made him make the mistake" :

There is something that most people ignore: when Allah makes a creation, He knows perfectly its destiny, its future and what will happens to and what he will make as choices etc...
But what is the meaning of giving them a "Brain" ?

In fact, allah gives you multiple choices and roads to follow during your life, but he gives you a brain to make the good choices at the right time. and satan just didn't (because djinns, angels or satan have brain too and can make their own choices)

2/ Indeed, satan was out of Janna; if you have noticed that among satan-symbols we find a "Snake"... this is because satan asked a serpent for help to get into Janna, then the snake agreed and swallowed him and made him get into Janna without being seen by its guardians.

People may say, if Allah knows everything then why did he let him pass, it's obvious, to test his creations choices. Now some say, if allah knows every creature choice, then he would have known about Adam and Hawwa choice, so why he let ibliss get in? Then, that was to move Adam and his wife to Earth to prove to satan at the end that he was wrong (means that he will not be capable of infuencing them and their children) and that he deserves the punishment he has.

3/ Satan is among djinns and of course have choice to convert to islam

Hope this helped you

Comment: Snake that swollen Satan? does this have any resources or just own opinion and thought?

Comment: yes you can find this story in "Hadith" words of Mouhamad saas... i don't remember the hadith exactly but it is very known if you search for it you will find it